# Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, lsa

I am looking for any tutorial or implementation of PLSA in java. There is a similar question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396463/probabilistic-latent-semantic-analysis-indexing-in-java  , however, there is no reply to this query swell. I have watched a talk on PLSA by Thomas Hoffman, however I can't seem to get my head around the implementation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis):

```
P(w,d) = \sum_c P(c) P(d|c) P(w|c) = P(d) \sum_c P(c|d) P(w|c)
```

That is the formula you need to implement.

Further, the [EM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM_algorithm) is what you need.  If you don't understand the algorithm or the function you cannot successfully be a consumer of it.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The info seems to be a good starting point.